# New email settings dialog broken in IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-usage

I don't understand the new email settings dialog:

[image]

Very confused whether that sends me emails every three hours (as per the drop down) or not at all (as per the checkbox). I'm unable to uncheck the box.

Comment: confirmed, rendering is broken in IE8. We'll have to get a workaround in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an issue in the html being rendered that other browsers glossed over - IE8 is such a stickler for valid markup :)

Answer (score 2):

What browser is that rendering in?  Chrome's rendering still makes it clear that the drop down only applies when the top button is selected - but that won't help you with no top button at all.

[image]

Comment: It was IE8 but this has been confirmed as a problem with IE8. It was fixed over in the SharePoint site so maybe it's fixed here too.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in Firefox too

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works OK in Safari (5.0.6) -- Smells like a browser bug Rob.

When it renders correctly it's pretty self-explanatory :-)

Comment: You can smell bugs?

Comment: @MarkM, don't you have "stink beetles" in your part of the world? You can smell them from a fair way off.

Comment: @MarkM And those "flying ants"... Almost a sweet, floral, or citrus smell. Right at the start of each autumn around here.

Comment: I was more referring to the fine scent of a June Bug hitting the wires on a bug zapper.  Smells like bacon!

Comment: Browser quirk I would say more than a bug. It's easy to say in hindsight they got IE8 wrong but that's hindsight for you!

Comment: @RobNicholson - actually per the accepted answer the got IE8 (too) correct, so it was a bug with the SE codebase.  It's easy to point at IE and say it's broken though, as it has a long history of . . . how do I say this politely . . . sucking so hard it blows ;)